# How are accountgenerators with captchas still possible?

Tags: attacks, botnet, captcha, bot

I was asking myself, how there are still account generators (e.g. for Steam) wide available for everyone.

With account generators I mean programs, that are automatically creating a huge amount of accounts to scam people or something like this.

Is it that easy to just bypass those tests without a big pricing or even for free?
I did a bit of research and saw sites like https://2captcha.com/ where you can solve a captcha using an API or public github-repos to generate those account by yourself.

Does those sides simply don't have a big drawback or are there any modern ways to solve this problem without asking for credit cards?

Comment: Your draft is incomplete, therefore the question is not clear. 1) what are 'accountgenerators'? 2) your last sentence needs more explanation and we don't research in random companies so you will have to refine your question to something more general. If you're asking why it's so cheap to solve many captcha's that's not for here. Otherwise your question end up in "How do companies protect themselves against a mass of humans (captcha solvers)?"

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. I edited my question a bit. Basically I wanted to ask which alternatives there are, how effective they are compared with captchas and why they are still used.

Comment: Your new version is helping us all and I think It's answerable still I can't get where 'credit cards' are referring to because it's introduced spontaneously.

Comment: With credit cards I meant a (quite inconvenient) solution to verify, that an account was created by a human.

Comment: Maybe because captchas have outlived their usefulness, computers have been better at solving them than humans for many years already. Honeypot fields and ip reputation are better alternatives, but if there is sufficient reward then it can be manually done by low wage workers. IMHO the only way to really stop bots 100% is to build in a cost model that benefits you or tie it to a real world attribute that is harder to fake, such as charging 1 cent to a credit card or validation code via sms.